# MouseEvents with JUNG and Java

Tags: java, jung

I made a PluggableGraphMouse and 2 EditingGraphMousePluggings in my Java with JUNG program.  If I set the modifiers to be left click and right click it works perfectly fine, here is the setModifiers code:

```
ovalMouse.setModifiers(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
circleMouse.setModifiers(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
```

What I'd like however is to have left click do one thing and SHIFT + left click (instead of right click) do the other.  I've tried every combination I can think of but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here are some of the more logical combinations I've tried that don't work:

```
//My logic here is Button1 AND Shift is down but this doesn't work
circleMouse.setModifiers(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK & MouseEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);

// My logic here is Button1 AND Shift but this doesn't work either
circleMouse.setModifiers(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK & MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK);

// Also tried InputEvents but those didn't work either
circleMouse.setModifiers(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK & InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
```

If anyone knows what the correct modifiers are so I can use button 1 for ovalMouse and button 1 + shift for circleMouse please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To filter Shift+Button3 in any `JUNG2`'s xxxGraphMousePlugin mouse event that implements `MouseListener`:

```
    System.out.println(circleMouse.getModifiers());
    if (( circleMouse.getModifiers() & (MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK | MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)) == (MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK | MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)){
        System.out.println(MouseEvent.getMouseModifiersText(circleMouse.getModifiers()));
    }
```

---

**Update**

So, if you want to differentiate a mouse event between `BUTTON3` and `SHIFT+BUTTON3`, the following test will show you:

```
graphMouse.add(new MyPopupGraphMousePlugin());

protected class MyPopupGraphMousePlugin extends AbstractPopupGraphMousePlugin
implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    protected void handlePopup(MouseEvent e) {
        boolean filtered1 = false;
        boolean filtered2 = false;

        System.out.println(e.getModifiers());
        if (( e.getModifiers() & (MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK | MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)) == (MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK | MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)){
            filtered1 = true;
        }
        if (( e.getModifiers() & (MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)) == (MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)){
            filtered2 = true;
        }

        if(filtered2 == true) {
            System.out.println("BUTTON3");
        }
        if(filtered1 == true) {
            System.out.println("SHIFT+BUTTON3");
            //or do something more useful like pop up a JPopupMenu
        }       
    }
}
```

In the above test under `JUNG2`:

1. **With the SHIFT key**: pressing `SHIFT+BUTTON3` (SHIFT key + right-click mouse button) will show both "BUTTON3" and "SHIFT+BUTTON3" messages
2. **Except the SHIFT key**: pressing `any key + BUTTON3` (any key + right-click mouse button) will only show "BUTTON3" message

Comment: Hmm ... not sure how that helps me to be honest.  You've written a boolean statement that checks what the modifiers are, the issue Im having is with an int statement to set the modifiers.  If I write circleMouse.setModifiers(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK & MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK);  That doesn't fire correctly.  Does anyone knows what the setModifiers line is that is required to get that to work, not the getModifiers line.

Comment: Actually, I don't see any impact `JUNG` will do with a MouseEvent's `setModifiers(int)` from my own test. In my test, the modifiers will accept an `int` value where the value is the combination of one or more `MouseEvent` constants that you are interested in. For example: `MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK (0x1) | MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK (0x4) == 0x5`  will be true when meta key `SHIFT+BUTTON3` is chosen, obtained from MouseEvent's `getModifiers()`. See my update

Comment: To summarize: you need to use bitwise OR '|' instead of bitwise AND '&' to combine the masks.