# Custom MouseMenu using EditingModalGraphMouse Plugin in JUNG 2.0 Java Framework

Tags: java, swing, graph, jung

I am trying to override the default mouse menu, while adding vertex and edges to the graph. I was following this example, as it works fine but i want to know what (interfaces do i need to implement if any) or changes do i have to make in order to change mouse cursor and also be able to add vertex/edge using right click instead of left click:

```
public class PopupVertexEdgeMenuMousePlugin<V, E> extends AbstractPopupGraphMousePlugin {
    private JPopupMenu edgePopup, vertexPopup;

    public PopupVertexEdgeMenuMousePlugin() {
        this(MouseEvent.BUTTON3);
    }

    public PopupVertexEdgeMenuMousePlugin(int modifiers) {
        super(modifiers);
    }

    protected void handlePopup(MouseEvent e) {
        final VisualizationViewer<V,E> vv =
                (VisualizationViewer<V,E>)e.getSource();
        Point2D p = e.getPoint();

        GraphElementAccessor<V,E> pickSupport = vv.getPickSupport();
        if(pickSupport != null) {
            final V v = pickSupport.getVertex(vv.getGraphLayout(), p.getX(), p.getY());
            if(v != null) {
                System.out.println("Vertex " + v + " was right clicked");
                updateVertexMenu(v, vv, p);
                vertexPopup.show(vv, e.getX(), e.getY());
            } else {
                final E edge = pickSupport.getEdge(vv.getGraphLayout(), p.getX(), p.getY());
                if(edge != null) {
                    System.out.println("Edge " + edge + " was right clicked");
                    updateEdgeMenu(edge, vv, p);
                    edgePopup.show(vv, e.getX(), e.getY());

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateVertexMenu(V v, VisualizationViewer vv, Point2D point) {
        if (vertexPopup == null) return;
        Component[] menuComps = vertexPopup.getComponents();
        for (Component comp: menuComps) {
            if (comp instanceof VertexMenuListener) {
                ((VertexMenuListener)comp).setVertexAndView(v, vv);
            }
            if (comp instanceof MenuPointListener) {
                ((MenuPointListener)comp).setPoint(point);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here, it adds vertex to the graph, using left click, i want to add this option on right click. And also it adds vertext/edge only in editing mode, how can i make it to do the same in Picking mode as well? or may be change the cursor while keeping the editing mode so it looks like picking mode?

Comment: Before any further discussion, you may refer to [MouseEvents with JUNG and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958622/mouseevents-with-jung-and-java) on how to modify the mouse modifiers

Answer (score 0):

i don't know right click for both edges and vertex same time but for one of them it works fine. it is for vertex . jframe is your frame your jung is added to.

```
    visualv.addGraphMouseListener(new MyGraphMouseListener<String, String>(jframe));
    ........
    private class MyGraphMouseListener<V, T> implements GraphMouseListener<V> {....}
```

EDIT : this can help you with both [Pop-up menu using mouse rightclick in JUNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544970/pop-up-menu-using-mouse-rightclick-in-jung)